# Select value when it different from time between time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Table:

[image: I have Table]

I want to get value like this:

| IP | Temp | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 172.16.24.96 | 31.5 | 2021-07-24 11:17:46.000 |
| 172.16.24.96 | 31.4 | 2021-07-24 11:18:31.000 |

When it have same value in interval just get 1 value with the lowest `Time`.

Comment: This is known as a gaps and island problem. Have a search of this term and you will very likely find your solution. If not, post **consumable** sample data (not an image) and your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "interval" you mean similar `ip` and `Temp`, then you can use the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT ip, Temp, MIN(Time)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ip, Temp;
```

EDIT

Larnu at the comment sections has pointed out that temperature might change and then change back. To cope with that issue, here's an adjusted query:

```
SELECT current.ip, current.Temp, current.Time
FROM yourtable current
LEFT JOIN yourtable previous
ON current.ip = previous.ip AND
   current.Temp = previous.Temp AND
   current.Time > previous.Time
LEFT JOIN yourtable betw
ON (current.ip <> betw.ip OR current.Temp <> betw.Temp) AND
   betw.Time BETWEEN (previous.Time AND current.Time)
WHERE (previous.Temp IS NULL) OR
      ((NOT (previous.Temp IS NULL)) AND (NOT (betw.Temp IS NULL)))
GROUP BY current.ip, current.Temp, current(Time)
HAVING count(*) > 0
```

Comment: @PeterB indeed, thanks for pointing that out. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that if the temperature goes up and then back down to a prior temp (or down and then back up) you may not get the results you expect here.

Comment: can i ask one more question ? i want get value Temp each time it change 0.3. can it be done in sql?

Comment: That changes the question quite a bit, @tupham . I would suggest asking a new question with your new problem. I also suggest provided more sample data, such as what happens if the temp goes up and back down (to a prior temperature).

Comment: @tupham that deserves another question that you may want to ask. If so, please feel free to add the link of that question here into the comment section.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad I need to wait 4 days before asking again. because rule .

Comment: @tupham I think you should be able to ask again. I do not know about rules restricting the number of questions that you may ask. It's true that I'm more on the answer's side.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(temp) over (partition by ip order by time) as prev_temp
      from t
     ) t
where prev_temp is null or prev_temp <> temp;
```